# Make a delay to a dynamic search (onchange) when sending data to apex (Lightning)

Tags: apex, lightning, search, timeout

I have a `<lightning:input>` which I send to the server the value inside it when it changes to search and return the closest results.

I tried to do the following :

*CMP - look at the lightning:input search*

```
<lightning:layoutItem  padding="around-small">
                    <lightning:card variant="Narrow" class="slds-card_boundary" >
                    <aura:set attribute="title">
                    <lightning:icon iconName="action:filter" size="small"/>
                    Circles
                    </aura:set>

                    <aura:set attribute="footer">
                            <aura:iteration items="{!v.circleListAdded}" var="cla">
                                    <tr>
                                    <td>
                                            <output class="slds-text-heading_small slds-truncate" value="{!cla.value}"></output>  
                                    </td>

                                    <td>
                                            <button name="circle" style="background-color: transparent; border: none;" class="slds-button slds-button_neutral" onclick="{!c.removeElementHandler}" id="{!cla.key}"><lightning:icon style="padding: 0.01px;" class="my-icon-style" iconName="action:close" size="xx-small" /></button>
                                    </td>


                                    </tr>
                            </aura:iteration>    
                    </aura:set>

                    <lightning:input aura:id="circleSearchId" type="String" name="circle" onchange="{!c.handleSearchEvent}" />

                    <table class="slds-table slds-table_cell-buffer slds-table_bordered slds-table_striped" role="grid">
                            <aura:iteration items="{!v.circleListSearch}" var="cla">

                            <tr>


                                    <a id="{!cla.key}" name="circle" onclick="{!c.handleAddingClickEvent}"  style="padding: 4px;" class="slds-text-heading_small slds-truncate" > {!cla.value} </a>
                            </tr>
                    </aura:iteration>

                    </table>


            </lightning:card>
            </lightning:layoutItem>
```

*Controller look at the bottom of the function (setTimeout)*

```
handleSearchEvent : function(component,event,helper){
        let controllerMethod;
        let mapName;
        let listForSearchDisplay;
        let timeId;

    switch(event.getSource().get("v.name")){
        case "fac":
            mapName= "v.FacMaps";
            listForSearchDisplay="v.FacList";
            controllerMethod = "c.getFac";
            break;
        case "city":
            mapName= "v.cityMaps";
            listForSearchDisplay="v.cityListSearch";
            controllerMethod = "c.getCities";
            break;

        case "country":
            mapName= "v.CountryMaps";
            listForSearchDisplay="v.customers";
            controllerMethod= "c.countryListToAdd";
            break;


        case "circle":
            mapName= "v.circleMaps";
            listForSearchDisplay="v.circleListSearch";
            controllerMethod= "c.getCircles";
            break;
        default:
            console.log("default");

    }

    console.log('TimeId',timeId);
    if(timeId){
        clearTimeout(timeId);
    }
    timeId = setTimeout( helper.handleSearchEventClicking(component,mapName,listForSearchDisplay,controllerMethod,event.getSource().getLocalId(),timeId),500);


}
```

*Helper*

```
handleSearchEventClicking: function(component,mapName,listForDisplay,controllerMethod,rId,timeId){
    timeId=null;
     var action = component.get(controllerMethod);
    action.setParams({
         inputText : component.find(rId).get("v.value")
    });        


    action.setCallback(this,function(result){
        var state = result.getState();
        console.log("state",state);
        if(component.isValid() && state === "SUCCESS"){
            var resultArray = result.getReturnValue();
            component.set(mapName,resultArray);
            var generalArray = [];
            for(var key in resultArray){
                generalArray.push({value:resultArray[key], key:key})
            }


            component.set(listForDisplay, generalArray);

        }else if(state =="ERROR"){
            console.log("Error",result.getError());
        }
    });
    $A.enqueueAction(action);
}
```

The error I get from running this code and start to type in the lightning:input is :

> Uncaught Action failed:
>   c:SortingListsComponent$controller$handleSearchEvent [Bind must be
>   called on a function]

But I don't sure that this is the right way...

I read about the

> $A.getCallback

But I don't sure this is the solution and how to use it in this case...

any help will be much appreciate.

Thanks!

Comment: What happens with the current code? Please edit the question to add this detail.

Comment: Just did @PhilW.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the timer event handler, it is using "this". I assume you want this to reference the helper. In which case you need to change how you set the timer:

```
timeId = setTimeout(helper.handleSearchEventClicking(
             component,
             mapName,
             listForSearchDisplay,
             controllerMethod,
             event.getSource().getLocalId(),
             timeId).bind(helper),
         500);
```

Note the addition of the bind which ensures that the runtime calls the helper method with the helper as the "this", otherwise the "this" is not going to work.

Comment: Thanks ! let me test it :)

Answer (score 0):

You can create an attribute to store the latest search id with name `searchId`. Then you can use separate methods for `keyup` and `keydown` to search and then remove the previous search id.

CMP:

```
<aura:attribute name="searchId" type="Object" />

<span onkeyup="{!c.handleSearchEvent}" onkeydown="{!c.handleClearSearchEvent}">
    <lightning:input aura:id="circleSearchId"
                     type="String"
                     name="circle" />
</span>
```

JS:

```
handleSearchEvent: function (component, event, helper) {
    let searchId = setTimeout($A.getCallback(
        helper.handleSearchEventClicking.bind(helper, component, event, helper)
    ), 500);
    component.set("v.searchId", searchId);
},
handleClearSearchEvent: function (component) {
    clearTimeout(component.get("v.searchId"));
    component.set("v.searchId", null);
}
```

Comment: Thanks ! let me test it :)